# Java Form problems

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I've recently delved into JavaFX as a C# developer. One thing I noticed in Java is that you're not spoon fed the way Visual Studio/Microsoft spoonfeed us.

So. When I was creating a form using the scene builder for IntelliJ Idea on JavaFX. I inherited "Stage" for my controller class and created a void called load that will load the instance of the scene from the FXML file. Therefore when I call load() from the Main entry point or anywhere it will load the fxml file and show.

```
LoginController frmLogin = new LoginController();
frmLogin.load();
```

The problem is that it works and it does't work.

Here's my code.

Main.Java

```
public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
       LoginController frmLogin = new LoginController();
       frmLogin.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

LoginController.Java

```
public class LoginController extends Stage
{

    @FXML
    private TextField txtUsername;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtPassword;


    @FXML
    private void btnLogin_Clicked(ActionEvent e) throws Exception
    {
        if (txtUsername.getText().equals("admin") && txtPassword.getText().equals("pass"))
        {
            Messagebox.Show("Correct Login!");

            this.show(); //The problem occurs here!
        }
        else
        {
            Messagebox.Show("Incorrect Login");
        }
    }

    public void load() throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("frmLogin.fxml"));

        this.setScene(new Scene(root));
        this.setTitle("JavaFX GUI");
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        this.show();

    }
}
```

Here's a GIF of the problem.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dntt7.gif

I want to know why when I call .show() it shows a blank for? 
Any help would be appreicated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have confused the different pieces that make up the application.

The FXML typically represents the "view"; i.e. the portion of the UI that is visible. It defines what controls are displayed and how they are laid out.

The controller implements the logic that is connected to (controls) the view. So it typically processes user input and updates the view in various ways.

A `Stage` is a window.

So, I don't think it really makes sense that your controller is a `Stage`. There are some scenarios where you might make a controller a subclass of a UI element, but those are somewhat advanced uses of JavaFX, and even then you would typically subclass a layout pane, not a `Stage`.

Here's roughly what happens when you call `load` on an `FXMLLoader`:

1. The `FXMLLoader` creates a hierarchy of `Node`s (UI elements) corresponding to the elements defined in the FXML file
2. If the FXML file defines a `fx:controller` attribute in its root element, the `FXMLLoader` *constructs a new instance of that class*. It then injects any elements with `fx:id` attributes into fields in that controller instance with names matching the `fx:id` values. It also registers any event handlers mapping to methods in the controller instance.
3. The `FXMLLoader`'s `load()` method returns the object corresponding to the root element of the FXML file.

So, in your code, you actually end up with two `LoginController` instances. You create one yourself in the `start()` method. You then call `load()` on that instance. That method calls `load(...)` on an `FXMLLoader` (via the really ugly static load method). Calling `FXMLLoader.load(...)` then causes the `FXMLLoader` to create an instance of the class declared in `fx:controller`. I'm guessing (you didn't show the FXML code) that class is also `LoginController`. So that is the second instance.

Now what happens, is that you get a reference to the UI element from `FXMLLoader.load()`. You put that in a `Scene`, and set the `Scene` in the `LoginController`, which - unusually - is a `Stage`. Then you make the `Stage` appear on the screen with `show()`. Note this happens in the instance you created in the `start` method.

When the user presses the button that has `btnLogin_Clicked` registered as its handler, the handler method is invoked on the controller instance: the one created by the `FXMLLoader`. That instance never had a `Scene` set, so when you then call `this.show()` it shows that instance of the `LoginController` (which, again, is a `Stage`). Since it never had its scene set, you see a blank window.

It's not actually clear to me what you intend with the call to `this.show()` in `btnLogin_Clicked` anyway. Assuming you thought this was the same `Stage` you had created from the `start(...)` method, that `Stage` is already showing.

The typical pattern is that you use the `primaryStage` that is passed to the `start(...)` method, and set a scene in that and show it. So you'd do something like:

```
public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("frmLogin.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX GUI");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

and then the controller is just a controller: it just handles the logic:

```
public class LoginController
{

    @FXML
    private TextField txtUsername;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtPassword;


    @FXML
    private void btnLogin_Clicked(ActionEvent e) throws Exception
    {
        if (txtUsername.getText().equals("admin") && txtPassword.getText().equals("pass"))
        {
            Messagebox.Show("Correct Login!");

            // I don't really know what you were trying to do here
            // but if you need a reference to the window containing the
            // associated fxml elements, you can get it from one of those
            // elements:

            Stage stage = (Stage) txtUsername.getScene().getWindow();

            //this.show(); //The problem occurs here!
        }
        else
        {
            Messagebox.Show("Incorrect Login");
        }
    }
}
```

Typically what you want to do when the user has successfully logged in, is to display something new in the current window. The simplest way to do this is just to set the root of the current scene to the content of a different FXML file. For example:

```
public class LoginController 
{

    @FXML
    private TextField txtUsername;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtPassword;


    @FXML
    private void btnLogin_Clicked(ActionEvent e) throws Exception
    {
        if (txtUsername.getText().equals("admin") && txtPassword.getText().equals("pass"))
        {
            Messagebox.Show("Correct Login!");

            Scene currentScene = txtUsername.getScene();

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
            currentScene.setRoot(root);

            // resize window:
            currentScene.getWindow().sizeToScene(); 
        }
        else
        {
            Messagebox.Show("Incorrect Login");
        }
    }
}
```

Here `Main.fxml` defines the main application the user sees, having successfully logged in, and defines its own controller class, etc.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I did at first and it worked. What I tried to do is how to have multiple forms whereby I can call it like. frmStuff.show(), frmGoogle.show(). just like you have in Visual studio. the show() method I created was like a IntializeComponent in C#? if that makes sense. So how would I make it so that I can call other forms to show and hide like I could in C#. How could I do frmStuff.show()

Comment: I haven't coded in C#. But to display a new form, you can just set the root of the scene to the content of a new FXML file. See updated answer.

Comment: Oops: I had inadvertently copied `extends Stage` from your controller to mine; I never intended that. I removed it.

Comment: I see thanks. But isn't that like cheeky?(I'm not saying you're cheeky, but Java is cheeky). As in, instead of showing a new form, you just change the layout of the current form? How would one open 2 at the same time according to that logic.

Comment: Well to open another one with the current one still showing, you would create a new `Stage`, and show it in there.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution*

Don't inherit Stage in your Controller.

JavaFX will implicitly create a Stage for your application and pass it to your application (the `primaryStage` parameter in your application start method).

*Sample*

Here is a quick update which should work.  Another alternative for this is to factor out the stage management as in James's answer.

```
public class Main extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("frmLogin.fxml"));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX GUI");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}

. . .

public class LoginController
{

    @FXML
    private TextField txtUsername;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtPassword;


    @FXML
    private void btnLogin_Clicked(ActionEvent e) throws Exception
    {
        if (txtUsername.getText().equals("admin") && txtPassword.getText().equals("pass"))
        {
            Messagebox.Show("Correct Login!");
        }
        else
        {
            Messagebox.Show("Incorrect Login");
        }
    }
}
```

*Aside:* I am not sure what your `MessageBox` class is, but JavaFX 8u40 has a built-in [Alert](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html) dialog box for standard message box style functionality, so that would be the preferred method to do that.

Comment: I used message box as a wrapper class to the Alert dialog class. But I will soon learn the Alert box class properly. I just find it a pain to write multiple lines when the same thing can be achieved with 1 line. Just like C#. Anyway, so then how would I show another form? if I had 4 other forms or stages. How can i do, form2.show(), this.hide()?

Comment: What is your definition of a form?

Comment: What is the relationship between form and stage for your application?

Comment: A form is a window. Apparently a form is the same thing as a stage